# Personal item size on a United Airlines flight to Asia

Tags: luggage, united-airlines

I am planning on going to Tokyo from USA via United Airlines for the first time. My carry-on bags and checked baggage are within the size limits, however, I have a problem with the personal item size limit of 9 inches x 10 inches x 17 inches. It is very small to fit my laptop back pack (16 inches), and I already have Targus Drifter II Backpack for 16-Inch Laptop that size 13.8 x 9.1 x 17.7 inches.

At a result, I have to buy the new laptop bag? (But I can't find it)
Or will I have to pay this fee when I board?

Comment: Thankyou for your answer and advice! My carry-on bag is 8.3"x14"x22" that United Airlines allow don't large than 9"x14"x22". However, in your comment I see they serious on carry-on bag than Personal item(laptop bag), so I will take my Targus bag 16inch but just leave enough spaceon. Thank for your advice again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I wouldn't worry about it.**  While carry-on item sizes can be enforced pretty strictly, nobody pays attention to personal items unless you're [*clearly* going above the limits](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Spaceballs-BH-03.jpg).  But if you want to play it 100% safe, just leave enough space in your carry-on to stuff the laptop if you need to.

For what it's worth, I usually travel with a carry-on rollaboard bag and a backpack, which is larger than 9"x10"x17", and have never been hassled about it.

Comment: This is my experience as well - while I've been asked to size-check or weigh my carry-on bag (Europe can have pretty strict weight limits), my normal-sized backpack has always accompanied me onto the plane without hassle, even if it contained multiple heavy laptops and was stuffed so that it exceeded size limits.

Comment: This probably apply to "traditional" airlines, which are usually not very concerned about carry-on luggage. At least several European low-cost airlines (and I am especially thinking about a particular Irish airline named after its founder Ryan) are however extremely picky with applying horrendous charges for anything slightly beyond their terms and conditions.

Comment: The OP is flying United.  Does anyone have any specific info on that?

Comment: @JoeBlow One of the problems with United (and I was a longtime 1P with them) is that they are so huge, and the Continental merger has gone so poorly, that there is not much consistency from station to station. I have had some of my best and some of my worst airline experiences with them.